# Populate a second dropdown menu from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have seen that some people asked before similar questions but none of them answers my problem.
I have a question regarding ajax and php. In both of them I am relatively beginner.

What I try to do is a so-called: chained select boxes. I want to have 2 dropdown menus. When I select a value from the first one, then the second dropdown menu it gets populated from a mysql database.

For this purpose I use jquery, ajax, php and mysql.

I was trying to find some examples online but all of them seem rather complicated to me (I guess cause I am beginner).

I decided to make something of my own but I got stacked. I am not sure if the logic is correct.

So here we go (I will include only relevant code here):

Using jquery I send an ajax request:

```
    $("#loc").change(function(){
     var val = ($('#loc').val());

        $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'query.php',
        data: {val:val},
        success:function(response){
            $("#x").html(response);
        } });
    });
```

"loc" is the id of the first dropdown menu. I get the value and I send it to query.php

query.php has the following lines of code:

```
 <?php

include('connect.php'); 
$area = $_POST['val'];
$query ="SELECT DISTINCT activity FROM main ORDER BY 1 where n_city='$area'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query) or die('no available data');
$options="";
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$activity=$row["activity"];

 }
 ?>
```

Now I am trying to figure out two things. 1) What should I return in the success function so I get a form which is populated with the results from the query? 2) Second and most important, is my idea actually correct or there is some logical mistake that I am missing?

Thanks a lot.
Dimitris

Comment: echo the variables which you need. Like we do in table. but u need to use option tag.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of this on the internet. While they may seem complicated, they will help get you the result you want.

Comment: Sarang: you mean something like this: echo $options.="<option value=\"$activity\">".$activity.'</option>';

Comment: In the `while` loop just build all the `<option>` tags you need for the #x `<select>`. A good thing is to avoid that direct $area variable injection, use a prepared statement instead. And you could get fancy returnin a JSON to parse in jquery instead of the `<option>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The clean solution would be to return a JSON array containing all the options for the second dropdown. This can easily be done by creating a normal PHP array and then using `json_encode()`. You can loop over the result and create new options in your JS function.
2. It will definitely work like this. However, it might be worth taking the time to learn how to use one of the available solutions.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to do what you suggest.